# How can I Redirect to an MVC page from a Web Forms Site.Master page?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

We re-wrote half of our existing ASP.net web application in MVC.  Currently in the old Site.Master page we call Response.Redirect("Default.aspx") and I would like to update it to take the user to the new MVC /Home/Index page.

I have tried these methods and they both return an "Unable to evaluate expression" exception...

```
    Response.Redirect("/Home/Index")

    Dim urlHelp As New UrlHelper(HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext)
    Response.Redirect(urlHelp.Action("Index", "Home"))
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Suppose you have hosted your application in IIS with the name "MyApplication" then redirect like this:

```
Response.Redirect("http://localhost/MyApplication");
```

This will automatically detects your Home controller and open Index view. 
Note: Before testing make sure correct page is opening while browsing:
"http://localhost/MyApplication"